# NodeJS: How would I compress a stream before uploading to S3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, graphql

Currently I'm uploading image files from my mobile app to my server, and then from my server to S3. Like so:

```
updateProgressPics: combineResolvers(
  isAuthenticated,
  async (parent, { pics }, { models, currentUser }) => {
    return pics.map(async (pic, i) => {
      const { file, filename, progressPicId } = pic;
      const { createReadStream } = await file;
      const stream = createReadStream();

      const { Location: url, Key: key, Bucket: bucket } = await S3.upload({
        stream,
        filename,
        folder: currentUser.id,
      });

      return await models.ProgressPic.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: progressPicId },
        { $set: { url, key, bucket } },
        { new: true, useFindAndModify: false }
      );
    });
  }
```

my S3 file:

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
import fs from "fs";

import { AWS_CONFIG, S3_BUCKET } from "../../config";

AWS.config.update(AWS_CONFIG);

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

export const upload = async ({ folder, filename, stream }) => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
    Key: `${folder}/${filename}`,
    Body: stream,
  };

  const options = { partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 1 };

  return s3.upload(params, options).promise();
};

export default {
  upload,
};
```

I'm using Graphql upload, which exposes the `createReadStream` function: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload#readme

The image files are kind of large (3mb), and I feel like they're taking a long time to load on devices even with Cloudfront. I would like to compress them before uploading them to save on storage space and for performance reasons. Is there a way to do this for streams specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess a library called `sharp` will be your friend in this very situation. 
I will have a link to this library over here and it widely supports streaming for all its operations. Hope you can solve your compression operation with this.

- Source: https://github.com/lovell/sharp
- Documentation: https://sharp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Regarding your performance factors, the library claims:

> Resizing an image is typically 4x-5x faster than using the quickest ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick settings due to its use of libvips.